# How do I view the IP addresses for requests in the Heroku logs?

Tags: ruby, logging, heroku

Is there a way to see the IP address for http requests in Heroku logs? I have used the command line interface 'heroku log --app {app name} but can't find an option to see ip addresses.

Answer (score 3):

As of 2014, the Heroku router log lines look like this:

```
2014-07-23T18:41:15.364378+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/help" host=thesquarefoot.com request_id=d0b9623e-e6b4-4723-8bac-b884da01d7e3 fwd="98.14.243.118" dyno=web.3 connect=1ms service=16ms status=301 bytes=360
```

the `fwd` value is the ip address of the request.

To see your logs, run `heroku logs --tail --app yourappname`

Answer (score 0):

do

```
heroku logs --tail -a app_name
```

and look for lines such as

```
2012-11-08T12:32:07+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for x.x.x.x at 2012-11-08 12:32:07 +0000
```